# non www to www with extra redirect

Tags: linux, .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently using the following code in my htaccess file to redirect all non www to www urls for the websites hosted in my server.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything works ok with most sites, but there are some sites who are still not open to the public.

In those sites i'm using a redirect to a folder which contains an "under construction page blah blah"

Following code

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
rewriterule ^mysite\/$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/beta\/beta\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Point is. when using the second redirect i get a loop and stop error in the browser, how can i work with both redirects at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/beta\/beta\.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^mysite\/$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/beta\/beta\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules in correct order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mysite/?$ http://domain.com/beta/beta.html [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule !^beta/beta\.html$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Not all the sites need to be redirected to --> /beta folder, just some of them. and that's the order of the scripts i'm using.

Comment: Understood but you probably misunderstood. Above rule is ONLY adding `/beta/` redirection to `domain.com` site (Not all sites).

Comment: it didn't work, looking for another solution at the current time. thanks

Comment: What do you want? an error log? there is no such, it's simply not doing what's expected, i'm looking forward to figure out why it isn't in order to add more information.

Comment: Q. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?